# Akka Stream : Outlet to FlowOps

Tags: scala, akka-stream

Is it possible to lift an `Outlet[A]` into `FlowOps[A, _]`? That is if I have this:

```
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.stream.Outlet
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{FlowOps, GraphDSL, Source}

def filter(in: Outlet[Double])
          (implicit b: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed]): Outlet[Double] = {
  val in0: FlowOps[Double, NotUsed] = ???
  val res = in0.grouped(8).statefulMapConcat[Double] { () =>
    seq => seq.reverse
  }
  res
  ??? : Outlet[Double]
}
```

To make that `grouped` call work as it would if `in` was either a `Source` or a `Flow`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was just missing the import of the implicits, then `Outlet` can be used for flow ops:

```
def filter(in: Outlet[Double])
            (implicit b: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed]): Outlet[Double] = {
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._
    import scala.collection.immutable.{Seq => ISeq}
    val grouped: PortOps[ISeq[Double]] = in.grouped(8)
    val flattened: PortOps[Double] = grouped.statefulMapConcat[Double] { () =>
      seq => seq.reverse
    }
    flattened.outlet
  }
```